# child div overflowing the parent div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I have 3 group of checkboxes, first two are given fixed width and the last one should take the remaining space. In the last group if the names are long, horizontal scroll appear for this group.

However, the last group is overflowing the parent div [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4162-forked-i2ohd?file=/index.css). how can I fix this?

Comment: How it should it look if the text is larger? Would it break into two sentences?

Comment: no the text should not break into next line

Comment: You mean the modal should be increased in the width?

Comment: no the modal width remains fixed.

Comment: I guess you got your answer from @Tanner

Comment: yeah that helped

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `overflow: auto` to the parent container `.select__content`, this way when content is too big to fit in its [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) and overflows, the scrollbar appears and the container `.select__content` container becomes scrollable. Try this out.

```css
.select__content {
  margin-top: 2px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here is the updated [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4162-forked-719cb?file=/index.css).

Comment: @srinivast6 Does this help solve your problem? Or do you want the third checkout group to be scrollable itself at smaller viewports and not the entire group of checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

.select_checkbox takes width auto which grows because the span element is very long. It can be resolved by giving .select_checkbox a max-width so it does not go beyond the specified width and the scrollbar may appear. Try adding max-width like this.

```css
.select__checkbox {
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 260px;
}
```

Comment: What does your code display in the jsfiddle sir?

Comment: yeah that is one way of doing it. But I don't want to give absolute width to it